Content Security Policy Blocked JS file from live reload
Essentially i have tried loading my site multiple times and cannot get the JS to work.
tester.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple HTML Page</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        header, footer {
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        nav {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        nav a {
            margin: 0 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
        }
        main {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Choose a country</h1><br>
<button function="onClick()">Grab my location</button>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="tester.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

the js file.

    function onClick(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallBack)
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
        }
    }

    function    successCallback(){
        console.log(position)
        console.log(position.coords.latitude)
        console.log(position.coords.longitude)

        alert("Latitude is "+ position.coords.latitude +" and "+ position.coords.longitude )

        function errorCallBack() {
            switch(error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
                break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
                break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
                break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser")
                break;
            }
        }
    }

It should be loading the button and asking for the location through the alert but it is not working. Nothing is showing up in the console either.
And then here is the output with the inspect showing me CSP has blocked my JS.
enter image description here

What server are you using that’s implementing live reload (and apparently adding a CSP)?

This will probably not solve the CS Policy problem but it should solve the fact that the button is not working.
To link a function to a button you add onClick='yourFunction()' inside the opening tag, not function='yourFunction()'. So it should be:
<button onClick="onClick()">Grab my location</button>

Alternatively, you can also link it through Javascript:
HTML: Add an id to the button and remove the onClick.
<button id="location-btn">Grab my location</button>

Javascript: After your code, call the button and attach an event listener to it:
document.getElementById('location-btn').addEventListener('click', function (){
       onClick();
});

